# Client or WiFiClient wrapper for adafruit CC3000 wifi other than web

Tags: arduino-mega

Basically I want a contact to a socket (keep open) for sending strings and characters as well as receiving them. I do not want anything to do with web. I am writing my own server in vb and actually have that working. I also have working the Arduino ethernetshield. I just wanted an alternative wifi solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your question question is effectively a duplicate of [**this one**](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/client-or-wificlient-wrapper-for-adafruit-cc3000-wifi). The only difference is that you're asking that it's nothing to do with the web. That doesn't really make sense because your network sockets will usually be the same, whether you're connecting to a local server or a remote one.